# Is this a real analysis result?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

For $x\in A[a,b]$

$\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|\ge\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

I'm just wondering if this is an analysis result or if the result is slightly different to this?

Sorry I just realised it was a greater than sign not an equals!

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  What is $A$?  Are you asking if the supremum of a function is always equal to its integral?  That's not even true for constant functions.

Comment: Your notation is confusing. $\sup_{a\in A} |f(x)|$ doesn't really make sense, there is no $a$.

Comment: Sorry I just realised it was a greater than sign not an equals!

Comment: Did you intend the limits of integration to be from $b$ to $a$?

Comment: Is your question really "if $f\in C[a,b]$ then $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|\ge\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$"?

Comment: Yes will fix that

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: The correct inequality is $sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)*(b-a)\ge\int_a^b f(x) dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ (and both are integrable) then $$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx \le \int_a^b g(x) \,dx.$$ If you then take $g$ to be the constant function $g(x) = \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |f(t)|$ what this says is that
$$ \int_a^b f(x) \,dx \le (b - a) \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |f(t)|. $$

Note that you do need the $(b - a)$ because if, for example, $f = $ the constant function $1$ and $[a,b] = [0,2]$ then $\int_0^2 1 \,dx = 2 > \sup_{t \in [0,2]} |1| = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a counterexample take $f(x)= 0$ if $x\neq a$ and $f(a)=1$. Then $$\sup_{[a,b]}f(x)=1\neq 0=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

Comment: This is not a counterexample to the inequality!

Comment: Is it true that $\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|\ge\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is always correct?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff that's because it was equality when I answered the question. That was an edit.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Originally there was an equals sign, and that is what Noah was responding to